# test_numb3rs.py catches numb3rs.py only checking if first byte of IPv4 address is in range expected exit code 1, not 0

Tags: python, cs50

This is the code of numb3rs.py

```
import re

def main():
    print(validate(str(input("IPv4 Address: "))))

def validate(ip):
    return bool(re.match(r"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.)){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$", ip))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this is the code of test_numb3rs.py

```
from numb3rs import validate

def test_max_min():
    assert(validate("1.1.1.1")) == True
    assert(validate("255.255.255.255")) == True
def test_alpha():
    assert(validate("abc")) == False
def test_incorrect_limit():
    assert(validate("1000.1000.266.1000")) == False
    assert(validate("05.1c2.02.04")) == False
    assert(validate("5.1111.1.1")) == False
    assert(validate("1.1.1.1.1")) == False
    assert(validate("1.1.1..")) == False
    assert(validate("1.1000.1.1")) == False
    assert(validate("1000.1.1.1")) == False
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

I tried to add the tests but it still result in an error

Comment: If it is some external test system, it says what it wants: you should communicate the testing outcome via exit code, not via return value. Python is not C. You can set exit code using `sys.exit` - e.g. `sys.exit(1)` to exit with code 1.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) to define a constant outside of the `validate` function so it doesn't need to be compiled on each call to it.

Additionally, you can just define the pattern for a single valid octet for an IPv4 Address and multiply it by four:

```
import re

IPV4_OCTET_PATTERN = '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1?[0-9][0-9]?|0)'
IPV4_PATTERN = re.compile('^' + r'\.'.join([IPV4_OCTET_PATTERN] * 4) + '$')

def main() -> None:
    ip_address = input('IPv4 Address: ')
    print(validate(ip_address))

def validate(ip_address: str) -> bool:
    """Validates an IPv4 address."""
    return bool(IPV4_PATTERN.match(ip_address))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Note that your octet pattern permits `011`, while one by OP does not. We don't have the problem statement, so I don't know what of these is correct, but IMO leading zeros should not be allowed (so it should read `1?` instead of `[01]?` in the last alternative)

Comment: Both approaches would work for the [problem statement](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/7/numb3rs/) since no test case tests for it. But I agree, I think in that case we need to add another alternative for `0` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with your numbers.py, but with test_numbers.py.
You need test cases where specifically only the 3rd or 4th segment is not in the valid range.

That is what the check50 error message is telling you - it is testing against a version (or multiple different versions of numbers.py) which don't validate each and every of the 4 segments, and your unit tests are allowing those flawed programs to pass.